# Laravel @foreach in a blade cause bug

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web, laravel-5

Hey This is A laravel home Page should show a list of the tasks of the user from Database, i have a problem that after some refresh the page i don't know why but it stop loading and show like the screenshots i attach in the question.
Any Help ?

```
@extends('layouts.app')
    @section('content')

<div class="container">
    @include('flash::message')

    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- Check if the user has any tasks to show -->
            @unless($tasks->isEmpty())
                @foreach($tasks as $task)
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <a class="{{ $task->state == 1 ? ' done-task':'' }}" href="{{url('/tasks',$task->id)}}">
                                {!! $task->name !!}
                            </a>
                            <span class="badge">@if($task->priority == 3)
                                    <i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x flag-important"></i>
                                @elseif($task->priority ==2)
                                    <i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x flag-normal"></i>
                                @elseif($task->priority ==1)
                                    <i class="fa fa-flag fa-2x flag-low"></i>
                                @endif</span></li>
                    </ul>


                    {{--@if($task->priority == 3) {{'list-group-item-danger'}}
                    @elseif($task->priority == 2){{' list-group-item-warning '}}
                    @elseif($task->priority == 1){{'list-group-item-success'}}
                    @endif--}}
                @endforeach
                @else
                    <h2 class="text-center">Nothing To show</h2>
            @endunless
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-block" href="{!! url('tasks/create') !!}">Create New Task</a>
</div>
@endsection
```

[image: First Image (full load)]

[image: Second Image (after refreshing)]

Comment: "_that after some refresh the page_" So it works the first time but after a refresh it bugs?

Comment: Reload your page several times, wait for the error to happen, and open page in developer tools. Look for the HTML code generated and copy-paste it to the question. It will show where it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `@else` statement out of context. Probably it is messing with your `@unless` statement.